# Detecting whether or not a catch block is being executed

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I have an error logging function that's used through existing code. If possible, I would like to improve it by detecting when it's called from a `catch` block to extract additional information from the exception when it's available. During a `catch` block you can rethrow the exception and catch it locally.

```
void log_error()
{
    try {
        throw;  // Will rethrow the exception currently being caught
    }
    catch (const std::exception & err) {
        // The exception's message can be obtained
        err.what();
    }
}
```

If you aren't in the context of a `catch` block, this function will call `std::terminate`. I'm searching for a way of detecting rather or not an exception exists to be rethrown, is it safe to call `throw;`? I've found [`std::uncaught_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception) but it seems to only apply to functions being executed as part of throwing an exception and is useless within the `catch` block. I've read through http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error but I can't seem to find any applicable mechanism.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    // prints "dtor : 1"
    ~foo() { std::cout << "dtor : " << std::uncaught_exception() << std::endl;  }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        foo bar;
        throw std::runtime_error("error");
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error&)
    {
        // prints "catch : 0", I need a mechanism that would print 1
        std::cout << "catch : " << std::uncaught_exception() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Workarounds I've found include simply implementing a different function to be called from `catch` blocks but this solution wouldn't be retroactive. Another would be to use a `thread_local` flag with custom exception classes to know when the current thread has constructed an exception but not destroyed it, but this seems error prone and would be incompatible with standard and existing exception classes. Example for this weak workaround :

```
#include <exception>

struct my_base_except : public std::exception
{
    my_base_except() { ++error_count; }
    virtual ~my_base_except() { --error_count; }
    my_base_except(const my_base_except &) { ++error_count; }
    my_base_except(my_base_except&&) { ++error_count; }

    static bool is_in_catch() {
        return error_count > 0;
    }

private:
    static thread_local int error_count;
};

thread_local int my_base_except::error_count = 0;

void log_error()
{
    if (my_base_except::is_in_catch())
    {
        // Proceed to rethrow and use the additional information
    }
    else
    {
        // Proceed with the existing implementation
    }
}
```

Does a standard feature exists to solve this problem? If not, is there a more robust work-around than the ones I've identified here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[std::current_exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) might be what you are looking for.

`std::current_exception` returns an `std::exception_ptr`, which is a pointer type to the current handled exception, or `nullptr` if no exception is being handled. The exception can be rethrown with [`std::rethrow_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/rethrow_exception).

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. It's right there near at the top of the page I've linked. I'll pay more attention next time! I'll accept as soon as the timer lets me.